# Keyboard Keys Randomly Swapped

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

So, I have a very strange keyboard issue. I have not installed or changed anything on my Windows 10 Toshiba Laptop (there was a windows 10 update though), but two days ago I noticed that some of the keys stopped working. When I opened the On-Screen Keyboard, however, I discovered that the keys had actually been remapped.

- <kbd>ALT</kbd> got changed to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> changed to <kbd>ALT</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> (Function) key changed to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> did NOT change to <kbd>Fn</kbd> however. So I can't really use that key unless I use 
  the on-screen keyboard.
- Windows Keys also didn't get remapped to anything and does nothing.
- Arrow keys also not working, but NumPad Arrow keys work as long as Num Lock is 
  not on.
- <kbd>Right ALT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> don't work at all, only the left ones got remapped.
- Options/Menu key (right-click shortcut button I believe?) does nothing.
- Everything else works as it should.

Did I accidentally hit a keyboard shortcut? I've tried to uninstall the keyboard driver and restart, didn't work.

At first Windows crashed and didn't restart properly. After a second restart, windows managed to install keyboard driver without crashing, but the issue was not resolved.

I've messed around with the keyboard language settings, like changing it to English-Canada then back to US, but that didn't work either.

This is a very strange issue that I have not encountered before. How can I fix it?

Comment: Related: [The Ultimate Guide To Keyboard Remapping](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/06/the-ultimate-guide-to-keyboard-remapping/). Check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` registry key, `Scancode Map` value.